# failed to read size in logcat error

Tags: java, android

I have a product2 class which contains setter and getter methods.
I also have two classes activity one of them is viewpager. 
When I click on the button to move me to the next activity a message comes

> Unfortunately my app has stopped

and when I took a look at the logcat error I saw two lines which are :

```
10-11 22:08:46.186 965-965/? E/installd: eof
10-11 22:08:46.186 965-965/? E/installd: failed to read size
```

I do not know what is mean

Is it related to my computer memory?

When I removed this code from the next activity it work perfectly 
it move me to the next activity but the activity of course is empty because there is no code

```
ImageView img2;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    private int[] normal = {R.drawable.ii1,R.drawable.i2,R.drawable.i3,R.drawable.i4};
ArrayList<Product2> listnormal = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
            viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

            for(int i= 0; i< normal.length; i++){
                listnormal.add(new Product2(i,normal[i]));

            }

            swipePage swipe = new swipePage(this,listnormal);

            viewpager.setAdapter(swipe);

        }


class swipePage extends PagerAdapter{

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Product2> list= new ArrayList<>();

    public swipePage(Context context, ArrayList<Product2> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);

    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third,container,false);
        ImageView bigimg = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewbig);
        TextView numtxt = view.findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
        bigimg.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImgpages());
        numtxt.setText(list.get(position).getNum());
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);

    }
}
    }
```

Comment: It will be better if you post the full log cat, to specify which issue you facing.

Comment: I post verbose logcat

Comment: you sure that log-cat contain the crash part?

Comment: How can i know ?

Comment: It should be a red font, appear in the log-cat after error occurs like [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html#running), BTW it's useful to read that link.

Comment: yes just these two lines                                                                               
  10-11 22:08:46.186 965-965/? E/installd: eof
  10-11 22:08:46.186 965-965/? E/installd: failed to read size

Comment: IDK exactly, but it's appear in these lines `I/lowmemorykiller: ActivityManager disconnected
 I/lowmemorykiller: Closing Activity Manager data connection`

That you facing problem with the activity, debug on that part of code to know which thing occurs this issue.

Comment: I edit the question. Can you see it again please

Comment: One observe I think your swiper shouldn't have the same main layout `inflate(R.layout.activity_third`--> `setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);`.